# Python merge with elements list(value, id) to element: list(value, value2, id)

Tags: python

Hello I have two lists with an id

```
[(u'0', 1), (u'3000', 2), (u'10000', 3), (u'20000', 4)]
[(u'2999', 1), (u'9999', 2), (u'19999', 3), (u'999999999', 4)]
```

both list will always have the id 1, 2, 3, 4
how could i merge the lists to have something like this:

```
[('0', '2999', 1), ('3000', '9999', 2), etc...]
```

Is there a easy way to do so?

i mean with zip i would get:

```
[((u'0', 1), (u'2999', 1)), ((u'3000', 2), (u'9999', 2)), ((u'10000', 3), (u'19999', 3)), ((u'20000', 4), (u'999999999', 4))]
```

but that is not what i want.
i still want the above and i really have no idea how i should do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to join elements *at the same position* you could do:

```
[(a,b,key) for (a,key),(b,_) in zip(first_list, second_list)]
```

Usage:

```
>>> A = [(u'0', 1), (u'3000', 2), (u'10000', 3), (u'20000', 4)]
>>> B = [(u'2999', 1), (u'9999', 2), (u'19999', 3), (u'999999999', 4)]
>>> [(a,b,key) for (a,key),(b,_) in zip(A,B)]
[(u'0', u'2999', 1), (u'3000', u'9999', 2), (u'10000', u'19999', 3), (u'20000', u'999999999', 4)]
```

If elements with the same "id" might not be at the same position you can sort them, using a `key=lambda x:x[1]` and then use the list-comprehension above.
Alternatively you can use `defaultdict(list)`, as in Ashwini's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a dictionary here:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lis1 = [(u'0', 1), (u'3000', 2), (u'10000', 3), (u'20000', 4)]
>>> lis2 = [(u'2999', 1), (u'9999', 2), (u'19999', 3), (u'999999999', 4)]
>>> dic = defaultdict(list)
>>> for v, k in chain(lis1,lis2):
    dic[k].append(v)
...     
>>> dic.default_factory  = None  # now missing IDs will raise KeyError
```

Now access items related to any id:

```
>>> dic[1]
[u'0', u'2999']
>>> dic[2]
[u'3000', u'9999']
```

Comment: Nice use of `dic.default_factory` however OP said lists will always be `1,2,3,4` so this method is unnecessary.

Comment: The thing is i still need the 'id' to be returned, since i will check the first two values and then return the id. else i would've used a dict.
but still great answer.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt You can do that with a dict too, using `dict.items()`, which  returns list of tuples containing both keys and values.

Comment: Oh thank you i will try that. 
And btw. really fast answers...
when i asked something in java, i needed to wait like 14 days, when i ask something in python, even on google groups i get 10 responds in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Use [map](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> a = [(u'0', 1), (u'3000', 2), (u'10000', 3), (u'20000', 4)]
>>> b = [(u'2999', 1), (u'9999', 2), (u'19999', 3), (u'999999999', 4)]
>>> map(lambda ((a,k),(b,_)): (a,b,k), zip(a,b))
[(u'0', u'2999', 1), (u'3000', u'9999', 2), (u'10000', u'19999', 3), (u'20000', u'999999999', 4)]
```

This won't work in Python 3, so if you want to use this method, you'll have to resort to the less understandable expression:

```
>>> list(map(lambda a: (a[0][0],a[1][0],a[0][1]), zip(a,b)))
[('0', '2999', 1), ('3000', '9999', 2), ('10000', '19999', 3), ('20000', '999999999', 4)]
```

Comment: bad choice of `lambda` over list comp, consequently this doesn't work in Python 3

Comment: @jamylak Hmm. Well that's annoying. I rather like my map/lambdas.

Comment: you would have to change it to `lambda x: ...` abd access `x` by indices for Python 3

Comment: nowhere near as neat though. Do you know why destructuring was taken out of lambdas in 3?

Comment: @brice: it was more of a headache than you'd think.  See [PEP 3113](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) for the history.

Comment: @DSM Thanks for the link. Shame, I liked that feature.